# How do i use same ssh key across multiple machines?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I've got a private Github repo I want to access from two different Linux machines using the same set of ssh keys

For the first machine, I followed [Github's instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) for generating SSH keys, and added the resulting public key to Github. This client works fine.
i uplaoded both my private and public key in GitHub gists to easily wget it on second client

In the second machine , I  downloaded the the private and public key to the necessary directory and gave relevant permissions.

```
wget -O /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub URL(RAW)
wget -O /root/.ssh/id_rsa URL(RAW)
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I thought this might be all I had to do, but when I try to connect i get the following error

```
root@InstanceIDInHexa:~# ssh -T git@github.com                                 

The authenticity of host 'github.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:RandomStringOfAlphaNumericCharacters.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
root@InstanceIDInHexa:~#
```

I also checked the content and permissions of all the files and it looks good

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
stat -c "%a" /root/.ssh
stat -c "%a" /root/.ssh/id_rsa
stat -c "%a" /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

is there something i am missing here ?

Comment: For future questions I suggest you anonymize your data. There is no point in leaving SSH Fingerprints, IPs or Instance IDs in a question.

Comment: @Uberhumus thanks for suggesting the edit , i will always ensure it doesnt happen again

Comment: Don't share the private key. If you have two machines, generate a separate pair for each machine, and push both public keys to GitHub. If one private key is compromised, it doesn't affect the other.

Comment: @chepner i know and i  have already tested , if i generate a new pair in my second machine and add public key to github , it works but for some reason its not suitable for me to do it  and regarding possibility of using same set of keys for multiple machines , it definitely seems possible according to some answers i saw on stack exchange - here is one of them - https://serverfault.com/a/170683

Comment: I suspect `wget` did something with the line endings; it may have dropped the final `\n`.

Comment: @chepner i dont think its wget because even if i copy paste the ssh keys manually and not use wget , i still get the same error

Comment: What are you pasting in to? Is your text editor saving the files in DOS format (CR/LF line endings and no trailing line ending)?

Comment: What operating systems are you using?  What are you generating these keys on and where are you copying them to?

Comment: @bk2204 i had generated these keys using termux on a android device . I am copying them to a server using ubuntu18

Comment: In termux by using ssh keygen*

Answer (score 23):

First of all, the best practice is to have one key per user per machine.  That's the most secure approach, because it means you can remove access from one machine independent from the other, such as if one machine is lost or stolen.

However, having said that, if you *really* want to do this and want to ignore best practices, you can copy the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files to a different machine, and that should work.  However, in this case, you generated the key on a newer machine which uses a different private key format or a more modern encryption algorithm for encrypting it then the older machine.  The default encryption for older RSA keys, the PKCS #1 format, tends to leave a lot to be desired and isn't very secure.

The easiest, simplest way to solve this problem is to generate a new Ed25519 key pair because those always use the OpenSSH format, and you can do that with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`.  If you want to then copy it, the files are `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`.  This is also the most preferred key format these days, but if you're using something ancient like CentOS 6, then it may not be supported.

If you don't want to do that, then you can convert the existing private key using `ssh-keygen -i` and `ssh-keygen -e` to convert your private key to the appropriate format.  This should be done on the newer machine, the one that generated the key.  The manual page documents the options and formats supported.  You can use `file` on that machine to find out the format that the private key is in.

Comment: i just now tried this.   Generated a new key par of ed25519 , pasted the public key in GitHub and first machine working well as always.. In second machine i copied both those files at appropriate location with correct permissions.  But i am still getting the error mentioned in question.                     Load key "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519": invalid format                           git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).